# QGIS grid doesn't fit

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules

I downloaded the German 1km grid and also create a 100m grid with the same EPSG code
EPSG:25832 - ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N

but the created grid doesnt have the same coordinates. Why did this happen?

[image]

source
https://gdz.bkg.bund.de/index.php/default/digitale-geodaten/nicht-administrative-gebietseinheiten/geographische-gitter-fur-deutschland-in-lambert-projektion-geogitter-inspire.html

Comment: Because your grid is based on a different starting point.

Comment: @Erik why the starting point is different, i dont find a setting for this on the grid creation panel. Or how to solve it?

Comment: What is wrong with downloading the 100 m grid from the same source?

Comment: You can alternatively use SAGA -> Transform vector layer and shift them manually by X and Y values

Comment: I want to understand why this coordinates doesnt fit and how to create it by myself. For me it is strange that there is a shift and because of it unclear how to use this function in a right way.